# For a new SSL certificate request do you need to include port?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I new a new SSL certificate for a site that will be accessed through https://xx.xxxxx.com:8443. During the CSR creation do I need to include the port number of the site for the site be recognized correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the certificate contains the DNS name and the port number is not part of the DNS name of your server.

Therefore just use the server name without protocol specification and port.